# Why the code about mmap gets the segment fault at the (16384+1) byte, not the (4096 + 1) byte?

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, shared-memory, mmap

OS is Ubuntu. 
From my view, page size is 4096, it should get segment fault at the (4096+1)th byte, but it gets segment fault when (16384 + 1)th byte is wrote.

Output: ... 16383 a segmentation fault

```
#include <sys/mman.h>   // memory management.
#include <sys/stat.h>   // file stat. man 2 stat
#include <fcntl.h>      // O_CREAT
#include <unistd.h>

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const int page_size = getpagesize();
    printf("page_size: %d\n", page_size);

    int shm_fd = open("shm.temp", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU);
    ftruncate(shm_fd, 1);

    char* begin = (char *)mmap(NULL, 1, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_NORESERVE, shm_fd, 0);
    perror("mmap");

    begin[0] = 'a';
    for(int i = 1023;/*i < .. */ ; i += 1024) {
        begin[i] = 'a';
        printf("%d %c\n", i, begin[i] );

        begin[i+1] = 'a';
        printf("%d %c\n", i+1, begin[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Updating:

```
int pid = getpid();
printf("pid: %d\n", pid);

printf("begin: %x\nbegin+4096: %x\nbegin+16384: %x\n", 
        (unsigned int)(begin), 
        (unsigned int)(begin + 4096),
        (unsigned int)(begin + 16384)
        );  

begin[4096] = 'a';
sleep(20);
begin[16384] = 'a';
sleep(10);
```

the output of `a.out &`:

```
pid: 3929
begin: b78a5000
begin+4096: b78a6000
begin+16384: b78a9000
```

the output of `cat /proc/pid/maps`.

```
b78a5000-b78a6000 rw-p 00000000 08:01 285615     /home/.../Try/shm.temp
b78a6000-b78a9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
bfb04000-bfb19000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
```

Thanks to Basile's good point.

Now the question is changed to `why there is b78a6000-b78a9000`. I am trying to figure it out. Any more info is welcome.

Comment: Perhaps you have some other `mmap`-ed segment. Check with `cat /proc/1234/maps` if your process is 1234.

Comment: Why are using `MAP_NORESERVE`? It is usually wrong when mapping a file.

Comment: Undefined Behaviour strikes again?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Uh? In Linux, [`MAP_NORESERVE`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) is often sensible for writable file-backed files, as otherwise your mapping is limited to the size of available RAM + swap. Is it perhaps because the process then gets killed by a `SIGSEGV` signal instead of getting an `ENOSPC` error if it runs out of disk space? I don't think that makes it *wrong*, per se.. It does impose some design limits, though.

Comment: Basile and alk both have a point; you are not guaranteed to get an error as you expect to. Note that when overrun detection is required, *guard pages* (non-readable, non-writable pages; `PROT_NONE`) are set up just for that purpose. As to the reasons for the behaviour you're seeing, maybe the fundamental block size on the underlying filesystem is 16k, i.e. `bash -c 'stat -f -c %S .'` reports 16384?

Comment: @NominalAnimal it still reports 4096 here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After i use `cat /proc/pid/maps`, i do find that some other mmap-ed segment.
Then i use `strace a.out`. I do know `why there is b78a6000-b78a9000`.

It comes from loader & run-time env before main function.

```
execve("./a.out", ["./a.out"], [/* 38 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x85d8000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb77f8000
... and something like it.
```

Related point:

```
g++ -static option!
```

Now i think i get the answer of this Q. Thanks for all your comment, especially Basile's point which let me think more.